# Web crawler capable of interpreting Javascript in python for Windows

Tags: python, webkit, gecko

My ultimate goal is to build a web crawler capable of downloading all of the images on a webpage.  My understanding from the reading I've done is that I need to embed a rendering/layout engine such as Gecko or Webkit.

Unfortunately, I'm running windows, so [PyWebkit is out](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t734935-ann-pywebkit-python-bindings-for-webkit-dom-alpha.html) and short learning C++ for Gecko or Java to use Rhino, I'm not sure where to turn.

Is there a reliable rendering engine with python bindings that will work in windows (64-bit, Windows 7)?  Is there an easy way to execute javascript within a python script on windows?

Comment: if this is just for personal use you might consider installing linux in VirtualBox and use pyWebkit from there.

Comment: Ideally it would run on windows so it could run on someone else's computer so the data can live on their system.  That said, by the time I showed them how to install python and whatever library I wind up using, I might as well just do it on my laptop and carry a jump drive over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Webkit to do that. All you need it an engine to run Javascript code, so take a look at [Gogole V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) or [Mozilla SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/).

If you're prefer Python to build your crawler, you may want to use [PyV8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) as it provides all necessary bindings.

Comment: Splitting tiny hairs: [PyV8 appears to only have a version for 32-bit windows](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/downloads/list).  Also, for others reading, installing SpiderMonkey on Windows appears to be nontrivial, but I found [this article how to do it](http://www.mailsend-online.com/blog/extending-spidermonkey-javascript-on-windows.html).

Comment: 32-bit shouldn't stop you. Just install matching version of Python and you're good to go.