# How can I control Firefox from R to handle AJAX/Javascripts

Tags: ajax, r, firefox, web-scraping, rcurl

I try to figure out a way of controlling a browser (preferably Firefox) via R scripts in order to retrieve information controlled by AJAX/Javascripts in Websites. For example, how could I retrieve the values in field "Modell" at http://www.mobile.de/home/index.html?

AFAIU, Gabe Becker's package ["RFirefox"](http://www.omegahat.org/RFirefox/) does provide some sort of link between R an Firefox. But being a Windows-Kid (not by conviction, but longstanding network effects ;-)), I couldn't try it myself yet so I'm not sure if it can do what I'm after.

So: is there anyone out there who does have some experience with either RFirefox or handling AJAX via R yet? Don't want you to do my homework, but before I plunge into the Linux world I'd just like to assess if it's worth it.

Nevertheless, any code examples would be greatly appreciated. ;-)

Comment: Not exactly what you need, but similar:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867105/parsing-html-and-following-a-javascript-link/7905861#7905861

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not clear on why you need a browser to do this.  It's just web scraping; it will require some kind of parser, certainly, but not necessarily a browser.  I think that RFirefox may be barking up the wrong tree.  If you want to play with Javascript+R connections, take a look at Duncan Temple Lang's [SpiderMonkey](http://www.omegahat.org/SpiderMonkey/).

Even so, I think it may be better to collect data with a more serious crawling/scraping facility suited for working with Javascript.  [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670082/web-crawler-that-can-interpret-javascript) seems particularly aligned with that.  My recommendation would be to get a tool that does what you need, and then interface that with R at the simplest level possible.  There are bindings for Webkit to several languages, albeit this doesn't seem to be the case for R.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998566/web-crawler-capable-of-interpreting-javascript-in-python-for-windows) addresses your situation even more closely: it is also on Windows.  It doesn't use Webkit.  The three suggestions in the accepted answer refer to accessing the tools, written in C/C++, from Python.  R has interfaces for both, so you may find it easier to write some stuff to work with these and pass objects and instructions back and forth between R and Python or C/C++.

Comment: Thanks for the advices! I'll check them out in more detail to figure out what would be the best way for me.

Comment: Okay, scanned through your links: 1) Always thought that the easiest way in the long run would just to "simulate" a real user, thus my idea of remote-controlling a browser. 2) SpiderMonkey: must have missed it, thanks for the pointer! 3) What do you think of Ruby in that respect? Worth a try or am I better off with plunging into Python for this task

Comment: I have very limited familiarity with Ruby, so my preference would be Python, though that's a personal decision. As the question is somewhat solved with Python and the Python community has a lot of R sympathizers (and vice versa), that might be a guide, though it's up to you.